# Terraform for loop through list with max range

Tags: terraform

I have the following local variables defined in terraform:

```
aws_enabled_azs = [
  "use1-az1",
  "use1-az5",
  "use1-az6"
]

az_max = 3
```

Then I use the following code to create some subnets:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "transit" {
  count = var.attach_to_tgw ? min(length(local.aws_enabled_azs), local.az_max) : 0

  vpc_id                = aws_vpc.this.id
  availability_zone_id  = element(local.aws_enabled_azs, count.index)
  cidr_block            = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 5, count.index + 1)

  tags = merge(
    var.tags,
    {
      Name        = format("%s-%s-transit", aws_vpc.this.tags["Name"], substr(element(local.aws_enabled_azs, count.index), -3, -1))
    }
  )
}
```

This should use up to a maximum of the first 3 AZs listed in `local.aws_enabled_azs`. However, this creates 3 subnets with an index of `[0,1,2]` What I would rather have is that the index is the actual availability zone ID: `[use1-az1, use1-az5, use1-az6]`

The idea being that if someone were to change the list of enabled AZs by adding / removing / reordering the list, Terraform would not modify existing subnets that are still in the list of `aws_enabled_azs` regardless of the order, and it would still limit it to the first 3 AZs in the list.

I know a `for_each` and/or `for` loop can do this, but how do I add in the max range of 3?

Answer (score 3):

you could use the slice function to take only N number of elements from the list and then iterate over them in the for_each

```
locals {
  aws_enabled_azs = [
    "use1-az1",
    "use1-az5",
    "use1-az6"
  ]

  az_max = 2
}

resource "null_resource" "null" {
  for_each = toset(slice(local.aws_enabled_azs, 0, min(length(local.aws_enabled_azs), local.az_max)))
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ terraform apply 

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # null_resource.null["use1-az1"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "null" {
      + id = (known after apply)
    }

  # null_resource.null["use1-az5"] will be created
  + resource "null_resource" "null" {
      + id = (known after apply)
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

null_resource.null["use1-az5"]: Creating...
null_resource.null["use1-az1"]: Creating...
null_resource.null["use1-az5"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=8739810057529525257]
null_resource.null["use1-az1"]: Creation complete after 0s [id=7109394796618656722]

Apply complete! Resources: 2 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Comment: This looks great. I will be testing it. Thank you!